Cannot continue installation because I don't have Microsoft account and Failed to create security key
I'm resetting my new laptop and re-installing Windows 10 Pro today (June 22, 2024) using installer media and directly downloaded from internet. Clean install and remove all files.
After installation, but still in the middle of setup, (to be exact, after selecting regional and keyboard layout) the installer ask to enter email, with note that says "..usually looks like someone@example.com or someone@example.onmicrosoft.com", but my account ends with @outlook.com (which is rejected by the installer, I tried using my skype username - because I suppose it's registered as Microsoft product, but also failed), and the only option is "Sign in with a security key".
So, on another laptop (running Linux), I'm trying to create the passkey on USB from the account.microsoft.com website, then, on Security Menu and 'new way to sign in' and I choose 'security key', but when I clicked it shows popup with QR Code, and there's a message says "If you want to create a passkey for login.microsoft.com on a USB security key, insert and touch it now, I've insert my USB but nothing happened. I supposed this USB should be able to make the installation complete if it works, right?
Then I refer to this link : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/set-up-a-security-key-as-your-verification-method-2911cacd-efa5-4593-ae22-e09ae14c6698
On that link above, I tried on yet another laptop (running Windows), to create Security Key, but also failed because it asked for email address that I don't have.
So what should I do now? Is there no way to install windows if we don't have company account / microsoft account ? How to create one ? If I go with Windows 10 Home would it be different ?

You could try to bypass the whole LogIn process using command prompt. When it prompts u to choose a country or region, right at the start of the installation, press shift + f10. In the command prompt, use OOBE\BYPASSNRO and the installation process will restart, but, you could choose the option to skip connecting to a network, using a limited setup, it jumps you way faster through the installation process. The only downside is that u might need to use a wifi adapter for network connection since it has no drivers. If u run on cable ethernet, you should be fine. U can connect to ur Mic. acc. and such later with this aproach.

I finally able to overcome this issues, here's how:
First, the condition of the laptop I used is bought from second hand market, and it contained a virus; and that's the reason why I want to re-install everything.
After several failed attempts to reinstall as I mention in the question, I tried OOBE\BYPASSNRO as told by @Andrei Boar, but it failed, because the command prompt said the command is not recognized. I've tried disabled the Wifi and change the regedit as I found in this forum as well, but the issue remain the same.
Then, I tried to factory reset using command prompt by this command:

c:/ systemreset --factoryreset

And then, I enter bios and change the bootable into the USB which contains the Windows .ISO installation file, after re-install the windows, this time it has an option on the bottom-left of the screen says "I don't have internet connection", so I could continue the installation process.
